# Error: Server error: couldn't open file "Capture.png"

Tags: php, api, file-upload, twitter

I want to post an image on twitter but I can't. I am able to post only text message with twitter API.

The error is: Error: Server error: couldn't open file "Capture.png"

I use wamp server. The picture is in the same folder with the script.

Where is the problem?

```
require_once '../src/twitter.class.php';

// ENTER HERE YOUR CREDENTIALS (see readme.txt)
$twitter = new Twitter. ('raQBedybFLb', 'HWgN6Qt11jg0LY', '862846056-ndeGfMA83r9ldh', 'VMBvHDahXnGp');
$p='./Capture.png';
try {
$tweet = $twitter->send('testing twitter api', $p); // you can add $imagePath as second argument

} catch (TwitterException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: is it `$p='./Capture.png';` or `Capture.png`? You're using both.

Comment: Is $p='./Capture.png'; The picture is in the same folder with the script.

Comment: Same error when I use $p.

Comment: Works if I put C:/Users/CCA/Pictures/picture.jpg

Comment: $p=realpath('Capture.png'); Works

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$p = realpath('Capture.png');`